# In Pyspark, how to check if consecutive words in a text file start with the same alphabet?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have following text in a file:

```
Horrid Henry’s hound hunts in the massive Murree mountains. While silly stupid Samuel’s dark dreadful dragon likes to hunt in
skies.
Horrid Henry’s hound and Samuel’s dreadful dragon Dany are fast friends and like to hunt and play together. They call themselves
fantastic fanciful foursome.
```

I load this file and `flatMap` it as follows:

```
lines=sc.textFile("BigData test.txt")
RddWords=lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))
```

This converts it into a list of strings (Each word being a string). I want to check if three consecutive words start from the same alphabet. The expected output is as follows:

```
H => 3
M=> 1
S => 1
D => 1
F => 1
```

The occurrence of consecutive words starting with 'H' happens 3 times. Similarly occurence of consecutive words starting with 'M' happens only one time. Shown below is the detailed occurrences of these consecutive words.

```
Horrid Henry’s hound =>2
Henry’s hound hunts => 1
massive Murree mountains =>1
silly stupid Samuel’s =>1
dreadful dragon Dany=>1
fantastic fanciful foursome =>1
```

I can write python function that simply checks for three consecutive words in a string of words. But I can't think of how to implement that function on the parallelized Rdd named `RddWords`. If I write a map function it will be implemented separately on each x in Rdd `RddWords`. How will I work on consecutive words? Can someone guide me a little?
Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**

You will need to either have each line as a rolling trigram:

```
(word0, word1, word2)
(word1, word2, word3)
...
```

and then map a function `f` that extracts the information that you want.

**Solution 2**

Use the Dataframe API and apply a rolling Window Function with a length of `3`

Comment: Thanks a lot you gave me the right path. I have now formed an rdd as follows: 
`words=lines.map(lambda line: line.split()).flatMap(lambda xs: (tuple(x) for x in zip(xs, xs[1:],xs[2:])))`
It looks somthing like this: `[('Horrid', 'Henry’s', 'hound'),
 ('Henry’s', 'hound', 'hunts'),
 ('hound', 'hunts', 'in'),...,('They', 'call', 'themselves'),
 ('fantastic', 'fanciful', 'foursome.')]`
I think I can now tackle the problem.
Many thanks